# Object_detection implementation details

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I would like to understand how the recently-published [object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) models are prepared for use in Tensorflow with the long-term goal to modify one of the meta-architectures.

Is there a write-up on how the meta-architectures (such as Faster R-CNN or SSD) are implemented, or is reading the code the only way to find out? In particular, I understand how these meta-architectures are defined in general (as it is described in corresponding papers), but I do not understand how they are implemented in Tensorflow.

Even a very high-level overview, describing how the flow works in this context (or with an unrelated model) would be very useful. (I am aware of the short `object_detection` [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) and the [detection architecture guide](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10012), but that's not it.)

What is particularly overwhelming when looking at these `object_detection` models, say, from a Keras background, is that the models are defined using relatively-large `proto` and `config` files with scant comments, while involving non-standard layers. Furthermore, the procedure to obtain, e.g., the `frozen_inference_graph.pb` file used in training from the `proto` and `config` files is not obvious at all.

Any sources of information or hints are much appreciated.

Comment: the source code is too long, and very difficult to read, I tried to read it on myself but gave up. I really hope the writer can reorganize it

Answer (score 1):

I went through the code base last week for both the Faster R-CNN and SSD pipeline. I would highly recommend you go through the code base. The functions/methods are very well documented and if you know the specifics from the corresponding papers, it can be easily understood. For understanding how information from the `config` files affect the model, I recommend going through the various builders (within the builders folder). If you are using an SSD model for training, check the corresponding [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/a4944a57ad2811e1f6a7a87589a9fc8a776e8d3c/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py#L108) in `model_builder.py`. This is where all information from config is used to construct the instances of the various classes. `model_builder.py` is invoked by the `train()` function inside `trainer.py`

So to answer you in short, as someone who was in your shoes a week back the best approach I recommend is for you to go through the code :).